# Haskell Gloss : Making zoom, pan, and all that kind of effects for module Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game

Tags: haskell, gloss

Recently I have been working on making a game with Haskell, and we have been using the library Gloss in order to complete the graphic part. To make a game with Gloss, as you probably know, you have to use Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game (or IO game, that's not the main thing to focus here). My doubt is simple. As they say on their description of this module : "Pressing ESC will still abort the program, but you don't get automatic pan and zoom controls like with displayInWindow.". I have been trying to build those two effects but with no sucess. I made an accumulator in my state, called v, that gets the value of 1 when 'reactEvent (EventKey (MouseButton WheelUp) Down _ _) ((px,py),p,mapas,i,players,b,c,d,v) = ((px,py),p,mapas,i,players,b,c,d,1)' and then the function that makes the picture appear would turn it back to 0 after applying the effect needed, creating a cicle. What's the mistake in my logic?
Edit : Added the prints, that's what I am trying to get to work. Also, if anyone has a clue on how to make different camera angles, I would also appreciate some help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW4ZA.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEV3K.jpg

Comment: Please include a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can do that, but not easy since I have around 400 lines of code on what I'm doing. I'll try.